# xsl-fo alternate table header

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using XSL-FO for some project. I have a table which is in inside another table, just to help group information together (and it's working well). This inner table has, as a header, the name of a country. This table can be split in different pages.
I'd need to reprint the name of the country on the next page (which is working already) with the text `(continued)`.

So, at the bottom of page 3:

```
United States of America
... ... ... data
```

Beginning of page 4:

```
United States of America (continued)
... ... ... remaining data
```

How can I insert this `(continued)` when the header is repeated in the next page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the XSL for the table?

Comment: depending on what fo processor (and version) you are using, you can either use fo-markers or fo:table-markers

Comment: @Vinit It's just a regular table with several rows of just one cell each. Inside each cell, I have another table with the data itself (because the first table is just helping the layout)

Comment: @PhilVallone Do you have any example? Basically I need to extend the header that is already repeting in each page, but adding `(continued)` in the repeated header in the next page.

Comment: @igorjrr See my answer - hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using fo-markers. I tested in the [FOP trunk](http://ci.apache.org/projects/xmlgraphics/fop/snapshots/#snapshots), it will not work in earlier versions. The FOP team made big changes in the trunk regarding markers. In the trunk version, they are more inline with the spec. The example is not long; you will need to add content to demonstrate the continued markers over multiple pages.

```
<fo:root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="alternate-blank" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-left="1.0in" margin-right="1.0in">
            <fo:region-body/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="header-blank" extent="11in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page-even" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-right="1.0in">
            <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="0.80in" margin-bottom=".5in" overflow="auto"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="1in"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="0.5in"/>
            <fo:region-start extent="0in"/>
            <fo:region-end extent="0in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1" force-page-count="end-on-even" format="1" master-reference="page-even" id="ps-0005">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">HEADER</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="header-blank">
            <fo:block id="last-page-wp-d18e4446"/>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block line-height="10pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">PAGE FOOTER</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Content</fo:block>
            <fo:table line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%" space-before="6pt">
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                <fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold" space-before.optimum="12pt" space-after.optimum="6pt" keep-with-next="always">PARA TITLE<fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="primary-para-continuation" retrieve-position-within-table="first-starting" retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <!--fo:marker marker-class-name="primary-para-continuation"/-->
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <!--fo:marker marker-class-name="primary-para-continuation"> - Cont</fo:marker-->
                            <fo:marker marker-class-name="primary-para-continuation"/>
                            <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" keep-with-next="100"/>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:marker marker-class-name="primary-para-continuation"> - Cont</fo:marker>
                            <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">
                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="primary-para-continuation"> - Cont</fo:marker>
                                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" id="d18e2057">
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                                    <fo:table-body>
                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"/>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding-before="1pt">
                                                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" space-before.optimum="12pt" space-after.optimum="6pt" start-indent="0in" width="7in">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1.00)"/>
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(2.20)"/>
                                                    <fo:table-body>
                                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"/>
                                                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-column="always" text-align="left">
                                                            <fo:table-cell wrap-option="wrap" padding-end="3pt" padding-start="3pt" padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt" border-start-style="solid" border-start-width="1pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid" border-end-width="1pt">
                                                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"> - Continued </fo:marker>
                                                                <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" space-after.optimum="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Column 1 Header</fo:inline>
                                                                </fo:block>
                                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                            <fo:table-cell wrap-option="wrap" padding-end="3pt" padding-start="3pt" padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt" border-start-style="solid" border-start-width="1pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid" border-end-width="1pt">
                                                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"> - Continued </fo:marker>
                                                                <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" space-after.optimum="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Column 2 Header</fo:inline>
                                                                </fo:block>
                                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                        <fo:table-row keep-together.within-column="always" text-align="left">
                                                            <fo:table-cell wrap-option="wrap" padding-end="3pt" padding-start="3pt" padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-start-style="solid" border-start-width="1pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid" border-end-width="1pt">
                                                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"> - Continued </fo:marker>
                                                                <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" space-after.optimum="5pt">Data1  </fo:block>
                                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                            <fo:table-cell wrap-option="wrap" padding-end="3pt" padding-start="3pt" padding-before="3pt" padding-after="3pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-start-style="solid" border-start-width="1pt" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" border-end-style="solid" border-end-width="1pt">
                                                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="table-caption-continued"> - Continued </fo:marker>
                                                                <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt" space-after.optimum="5pt">Content</fo:block>
                                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </fo:table-body>
                                                </fo:table>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                                <fo:block> </fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```